# What is the correct way to configure Magento, so that products will be visible on storefront?

Tags: products

I am completely new to magento. Trying to add some products on store, product saved successfully. But it is not visible on storefront. Checked all the configuration settings, all are correct.

I found some solutions saying reindexing and cache flushing. While reindexing it shows -
' Catalog Search index exception: Could not ping search engine: No alive nodes found in your cluster '

Is that related to elasticsearch. If so, what should be the correct way to configure elasticsearch, especially for magento.

Also, sometimes reindexing worked successfully without any exception as above. However, product was not visible.

Using latest version of Magento i.e 2.4.2-p1.

Any help on that would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: you are check this in localhost?

Comment: Yes configured 127.0.0.1 as network host in elasticsearch.yml